# What is the baptism requirement for becoming a Mennonite?

Tags: baptism, mennonite

Historically, Mennonites and other Anabaptists practiced adult re-baptism when a Catholic or Lutheran converted.  This got them in a lot of hot water at the time.

As a long-time member of a General Conference Mennonite Church (now the [Mennonite Church USA](http://www.mennoniteusa.org/)), and a current member of a [Mennonite Brethren](http://www.usmb.org/) church, my impression is that when a Catholic (or other person baptized as an infant) becomes a Mennonite, they are generally given the option of re-baptism, but it's not considered a requirement.  But admittedly, this doesn't happen very often in the U.S.

And in Mexico, where practically everyone is born Catholic (and therefore baptized as an infant), re-baptism seems quite common; but in Mexico the Catholic and protestant churches are often quite at odds with each other (Mexican Catholics think "Christian" is a dirty word).

So my question is:  What are the *official rules* among Mennonite churches regarding re-baptism of new members of the Mennonite church?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things based on my own experience in the [Ontario Conference of Mennonite Brethren](http://www.onmb.org/).

It is a matter of doctrine that only those baptized 'of the age of accountability' are considered validly baptized. Baptisms of infants are not considered valid.

However individual churches are, I believe, able to set their own rules about whether baptism is required, and for what. The norm is that baptism is required for membership; but in many Mennonite churches people can be very active participants for a long time, even serve in leadership positions, without becoming formal members, and thus without being baptized (i.e. without being *rebaptized* if you were baptized as an infant). That was certainly true in my case.

So in short: if you were baptized as an infant you are considered not baptized: however that may not be much of a restriction.

Answer (score 4):

Baptism is a "sign" of redemption and commitment in the Mennonite tradition, not a sacrament as in some other Christian traditions ([Confession of Faith in a Mennonite Perspective, 1995](http://www.mcusa-archives.org/library/resolutions/1995/index.html)). Since Mennonite churches emphasize congregational and conference leadership, the practice of adult rebaptism will vary by congregation or region. There are no *official rules* for Mennonite adult rebaptism as such.

Comment: Very interesting tidbits. And welcome to Christianity.SE!